# Definition of nilpotent and solvable group

Tags: group-theory

Nilpotent group G satisfies there exist a sequence $G > G_1 > ... > G_n = \{e\} $ where $ \forall x \in G$ and $\forall y \in G_k$, $[x,y] \in G_{k+1}$. Solvable group G satisfies setting $G=G_0$ and $[G_i, G_i] = G_{i+1}$. I only learned that $A_n$ is not solvable if $n > 4$ And solvable for 2, 3, 4, and didn't used after, i.e. classifying groups, and now I'm learning ring theory. Why do we learn solvable group? Where solvable group or nilpotent group used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First example that comes to mind is Galois theory. It is a famous theorem that a polynomial with coefficents in $\mathbb{Q}$ is solvable over radicals if and only if its Galois group is solvable.

Also, within the theory of groups, sometimes to understand a (usually non-solvable, non-nilpotent) group it is useful to look at some solvable and nilpotent subgroups. For example, to understand Lie groups it is useful to look at its Borel subgroups (a subgroup which is maximal wrt. being closed, solvable and connected). In $\operatorname{SL}_n$ the subgroup of upper triangular matrices is a Borel subgroup.

I'm sure there are many other places where solvable groups are important. In group theory the concept of a solvable group comes up all the time.